# Numbers in scshape with font Palatino Linotype

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I recently noticed that with font Palatino Linotype, the numbers in `\scshape` appear to be quite small, as you can see from the section titles in the example below. Is there some way to make the numbers look normal?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Palatino Linotype}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\scshape}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries\scshape}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: Stylistic decision by the font designer?

Comment: @egreg This I agree. But is there some way to replace them with normal numbers (or old style figures) during font selection?

Comment: I can't see how, unless you use LuaTeX and its tricks.

Comment: @egreg It seems during the font selection process one can select the range of characters, so maybe one can select the small capital numbers from another font file. However, I don't know how to get the range of these characters.

Comment: You're confusing with `\setmathfont`…

Comment: Are you asking how to tell LaTeX to use Lining numerals in sectioning headers?

Comment: Could you use TeX Gyre Pagella or another free Palatino clone or do you need the proprietary Palatino Linotype?

Comment: @Mico Yes, I was thinking about that. But now it seems to me that this is not actually a big issue, as numbers should usually appear as either English word or in math mode. This unusual (direct) usage only occurs in command like `\blinddocument`.